# do I have to use Axon with Spring-Webflux

Tags: axon

I see a lot of Spring-Webflux codes in Axon lecture videos.
But I don't know anything about Spring-Webflux, so I'm trying to use Axon without a code for Spring-Webflux, is it a wrong choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axon definitely doesn't try to force you to use Spring WebFlux! The samples have been moving that way, as many benefits reside with the reactive nature of `Mono`'s and `Flux`'s. However, if you feel more comfortable with regular REST, AMQP, or whatever type of communication, Axon Framework will not block you on that endeavor.

If it's a *wrong* choice is a different topic, though. The samples are intentionally moving that way, as there's an assumption that that form of communication will be (more) standard. If you have time to also try out Spring WebFlux, I'd say it does not hurt to spend some on it.